# Why do I get successful registration message on my device while there is no change in server database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the code for sending push notification using gcm.
On my device I get the message "device successfully registered with gcm" but on the server it displays "No devices registered yet".

The database is still empty. 
I think there is some problem with the php code

here's the link:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

I have made the following changes: The API key, Sender ID, and instead of wamp I have used my own server 
**I have changed all mysql commands to mysqli but its still not working.**

Comment: That's some very old PHP code, you probably get deprecated warnings etc.

Comment: @Daan could u suggest some modifications

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, replace them with `PDO` or `mysqli_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

First register the device to GCM and get the gcm key. Send the notification to that device manually using the GCM key. Curl request to do so is

curl --header "Authorization: key=" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -XPOST -d '{"data":{"New message through curl"},"registration_ids":["APA91bGe-Ihcjil6YXgLNEtf1fZCvcrgcn35rTOsHPrK7mxoz70TP6jmniChLXmIbLd642CWGo0fem9XrECa2ukvAvNYfNY7HcJ0JcxTInBxNn5Pml9YQIU6qwRVQ4v8GIE4oZv4vjoc"]}'

If you get the notification using this then your device has been registered successfully

Also you can send the notifications to multiple devices using notification key

Check the url for more info
https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/notifications-d7df385b0ff4